# Filter files by multiple categories on Wikipedia

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

How can I find files on Wikipedia (or the Wikimedia Commons) that are in two or more specific categories? For instance, if I was searching for files to put into the category "dogs and cats", I would want to find all of the files that were in both the category "dogs" and the category "cats." How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CatScan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCatScan) to do that.

For example, to query files on Commons, you can start with [http://toolserver.org/~magnus/catscan_rewrite.php?language=commons&project=wikimedia&ns[6]=1](http://toolserver.org/~magnus/catscan_rewrite.php?language=commons&project=wikimedia&ns%5b6%5d=1) and enter the categories you want into the Categories box.

Comment: For CatScan, how can you enter multiple categories and negative categories? Should they be separated by commas?

Comment: Just put them on separate lines.